# Creating dynamic buttons on Activity B from Activity A

Tags: java, android

I have three activities, we'll call them: `MainActivity`, `MenuActivity`, and `DataActivity`.

`MainActivity` is static, hardcoded and will not be changing. It consists of 9 buttons which ideally lead to different Menu selections. Originally I have had each Menu/subtopic of the MainActivity be housed in its own Activity (yeilding 9 menu activities), but my goal is to create one `MenuActivity` and update it dynamically depending on the button pressed on the `MainActivity`.

The `MenuActivity` has 10 buttons. I have tried creating a separate class for each subtopic (buttons of the `MainActivity`) with the goal of each class to use `setText()` and add a unique `onClickListener()`. This is failed in several different ways, from not being able to apply the `onClickListener()` to failing to set the text of the buttons.

My current theories are to try to create buttons dynamically on the `MenuActivity` when a button is pressed on the `MainActivity`

Example:  `btnTopic1` is pressed on MainActivity --> `MenuActivity` is updated with Topic1's nav buttons. The now dynamic `MenuActivity` set with Topic1's buttons will then have buttons that link to the `DataActivity` which ideally will be changing text dynamically.

What would be my best solution in this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: *What would be my best solution in this scenario?* Use fragments

Comment: I'll start researching fragments. Not very used to them yet. For the purpose of understanding - would I be creating a seperate fragment for each "submenu" then make the fragment visible when called from `MainActivity`?